# Is there a way to read a filestream until a period (.) is found. Then repeat?

Tags: c, file

I'm fairly new to C and not sure how I would do this. I've found similar questions, but nothing exactly like I want.

What I want to do is read a raw txt file "sentence by sentence" with the end of a sentence being considered a period (.) or a newline (\n). With no assumed maximum lengths for any data structures.

My first thought was `getline()`, but the version of C I'm required to use does not seem to have such a function. So I've tried to use `fgets()` and then parse the data onto a `sscanf()` with a scanset. `sscanf(charLine, "%[^.]s", sentence);`

The problem with this, is that if there is more than one period (.) it will stop at the first and not start again at that period (.) to collect the others.

I feel like I'm on the right track but just don't how to expand on this.

```
    while(fgets (charLine, size, readFile) == NULL)
    {
         sscanf(charLine, "%[^.]s", sentence);
         // something here...
    }
```

Comment: `malloc` a buffer, then read one character at a time into the buffer. If you find a period or newline, the buffer contains a sentence. If the buffer fills up, use `realloc` to make it bigger, and then keep reading. The `fgets` solution won't work because of the *"no assumed maximum lengths"* constraint.

Comment: I recommend you look at the string examination functions in https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte, `strrchr` in particular.

Comment: How about traversing `charLine` and replacing `.` with `NULL` then you can get separate string by remembering position next to `NULL`

Comment: @user3386109 So use `fgetc` instead of `fgets`? The maximum length constraint isn't  a problem with `fgets` because I've already done as you suggested with a buffer; `realloc` when it fills.

Comment: Ok, then you can use `strtok` with `".\n"` as the delimiter to break the line into sentences.

Comment: Do you need to store all sentences in memory for later use, or do you simply want to read the raw text file and write the sentences out one-by-one? To write the sentences out, you need nothing more than `fgetc()` and a couple of `if` statements. To store everything without limit, you will need to allocate and reallocate a pointer for each sentence, and then storage for each sentence.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm using it to construct a correlation matrix. which takes the words that start with capital letters and counts how many times that words occurs in the same sentence with another. So, I shouldn't need the sentences again.

Comment: Then you don't need to dynamically allocate anything. The longest word in the unabridged non-medical dictionary is 29-chars. Just use a fixed buffer for 128-char to store each word (don't skimp on buffer size), and test and add to your correlation matrix as you read each sentence. You need 2-flags. (1) an `insent` to indicate in-a-sentence, and (2) `inword`. Just set to 1 if in either, or 0 otherwise. This allows you to skip whitespace between sentences and words. Then it's just a matter of reading each char until `EOF` and 4-5 tests for sentence/word start end (*nul-terminate* each word)

Comment: Regarding: `"%[^.]s"`  This is NOT a valid format string.  Because it is VERY UNLIKELY that a sentence ending with a '.' will have the very next character be a 's'.  Suggest using: `"%[^.\n]"` so it will catch either a period or a newline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a function that reads the stream until a `.` or a newline is found. David C.Rankin suggested that just scanning for a `.` might be too restrictive, causing embedded periods in www.google.com to act as sentence break. One can stop on `.` if followed by white space:

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* alternative to fgets to stop at `.` and newline */
char *fgetsentence(char *dest, size_t size, FILE *fp) {
    size_t i = 0;
    while (i + 2 < size) {
        int c = getc(fp);
        if (c == EOF)
            break;
        dest[i++] = (char)c;
        if (c == '\n')
            break;
        if (c == '.') {
            int d = getc(fp);
            if (d == EOF)
                break;
            if (isspace(d)) {
                dest[i++] = (char)d;
                break;
            }
            ungetc(d, fp);
        }
    }
    if (i == 0)
        return NULL;
    dest[i] = '\0';
    return dest;
}
```

If you want to handle arbitrary long sentences, you would take pointers to `dest` and `size` and reallocate the array if required.

Note that it would be very impractical to use `fscanf(fp, "%[^.\n]", dest)` because it is not possible to pass the maximum number of bytes to store into `dest` as an evaluated argument and one would need to special case empty lines and sentences.

Note too that stopping on `.`, even with the above restriction that it must be followed by white space still causes false positives: sentences can contain embedded periods followed by white space that are not the end of the sentence. Example: *Thanks to David C. Rankin for his comments on my answer.*

Comment: Would this go through the entire file? For example if I had 
en.wikipedia.org would it assign `dest` as en, then wikipedia, then org?

Comment: A "sentence" and splitting a host.domain.tld are two separate things. If you had a sentence like `"Sites like en.wikipedia.org are references."`, you would get `"Sites like en"` then `"wikipedia"` finally `"org are references"` -- Is that what you want?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: interesting point. I guess the function would check if `.` is followed by some white space.

Comment: I'm just really confused as to exactly what is being asked. It seems to cover everything from read any length of sentence without limitation, to parsing the host and domain components of a site to running correlations on the number of times the same word appears capitalized in each sentence -- so he may be asking for 3-4 different things as one.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: The OP's sentence *The problem with this, is that if there is more than one period (.) it will stop at the first and not start again at that period (.) to collect the others.* refers to `fgets()`: extracting a sentence from the line read by `fgets()` is not enough, the remainder of the line being ignored in his attempts.

Comment: My question was simply how it deals with characters that follow a `.` without white space. I'm getting confused because I'm using an unformatted txt file as a reference that doesn't show formatting, making it seem as if AustraliaA is one word not separated when it's actually 2 words seperated by a newline.

Comment: @Aevitas: if you remove the newline from the input, and not separate different input lines in your output, you will effectively glue the last word of a line with the first word of the next line. Replace the newline with a space instead of removing it.

Comment: If you want to read an entire wikipedia article this way, you would need to parse the html format to handle the tags specifically and you probably want a lage array or a reallocation method.

Comment: @chqrlie How exactly would I realloc this?